# How to skip creation of one of the test databases in Django

Tags: python, django, database-migration

We have two databases we work with in our Django application, a "transactional" one and an "analytical" one (serving as a data warehouse). The "transactional" one is created using django models and the "analytical" one is created using our custom scripts containing raw sql of multiple joins of the "transactional" ones tables.

When we run tests for the django app, both of the databases get their test counterpart versions created, let's say, "test_transactional" and "test_analytical". The creation of the "test_transactional" is ok, but we would like for the creation of the "test_analytical" to be skipped since that one will be created and filled by our custom scripts.

Snippet from jenkins logs:

```
python manage.py test --keepdb cis.tests.test_views --  
noinput --settings=strainprint.settings.local --verbosity=2
...
Using existing test database for alias 'analytics' 
('test_strainprint_analytics')...
...
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
Creating tables...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Django? We are using django 1.10.

Answer (score 4):

As requested, here's what I ended up implementing. A "legacy" database here is a database for which we want to skip creation---Django should assume that it already exists.

You will first need to add this lightly modified test runner, `project/runner.py`:

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from django.test.utils import get_unique_databases_and_mirrors
from django.db import connections


class LegacyDatabaseRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    """
    Test runner that will skip attempting to create any database with LEGACY=True
    in its TEST configuration dictionary
    """
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        return _setup_databases(
            self.verbosity, self.interactive, self.keepdb, self.debug_sql,
            self.parallel, **kwargs
        )


def _setup_databases(verbosity, interactive, keepdb=False, debug_sql=False, parallel=0, **kwargs):
    """Clone of django.test.utils.setup_databases"""
    test_databases, mirrored_aliases = get_unique_databases_and_mirrors()

    old_names = []

    for db_name, aliases in test_databases.values():
        first_alias = None
        for alias in aliases:
            connection = connections[alias]

            # This clause is all that's been added. If the database's TEST configuration
            # has LEGACY=True, skip attempting to create the database, and don't add it
            # to the list of databases to tear down after testing is complete.
            if connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('LEGACY', False):
                continue

            old_names.append((connection, db_name, first_alias is None))

            # Actually create the database for the first connection
            if first_alias is None:
                first_alias = alias
                connection.creation.create_test_db(
                    verbosity=verbosity,
                    autoclobber=not interactive,
                    keepdb=keepdb,
                    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
                )
                if parallel > 1:
                    for index in range(parallel):
                        connection.creation.clone_test_db(
                            suffix=str(index + 1),
                            verbosity=verbosity,
                            keepdb=keepdb,
                        )
            # Configure all other connections as mirrors of the first one
            else:
                connections[alias].creation.set_as_test_mirror(connections[first_alias].settings_dict)

    # Configure the test mirrors.
    for alias, mirror_alias in mirrored_aliases.items():
        connections[alias].creation.set_as_test_mirror(
            connections[mirror_alias].settings_dict)

    if debug_sql:
        for alias in connections:
            connections[alias].force_debug_cursor = True

    return old_names
```

Next, make it the default runner in your `project/settings.py`:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'project.runner.LegacyDatabaseRunner'
```

Then mark any databases you want to skip creation for with `LEGACY=True` in your settings:

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': ...,
        },
        'legacy_db1': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': ...,
            'TEST': {
                'LEGACY': True,  # Do not manage this database during tests
            },
        },
    }
```

Then hopefully running `manage.py test` works as expected.

Note that this will *not* work when running parallel tests. I made some progress on that by patching `ParallelTestSuite.init_worker` and fiddling a bit more with `setup_databases`, but it's not fully functional yet.

### Old answer, may work in a pinch

This is not a particularly safe way to do it, since the semantics of this configuration option could change, but you can declare one database to be a "replica" of the other:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'transactional',
         ...
    },
    'analytical': {
        'NAME': 'analytical',
        ...
        'TEST': {
            'MIRROR': 'default',
        },
    }
}
```

The `MIRROR` configuration option is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#testing-primary-replica-configurations

Relevant Django source is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/utils.py

Comment: I completely forgot about this issue because I learnt to live with 5 minutes of test setup. So for some reason I've tried to use it now, but the issue is with this part (from the docs):
_When the test environment is configured, a test version of replica will not be created. Instead the connection to replica will be redirected to point at default._
This is a problem since my query which should go to the analytics database will get redirected to the transactional one which does not have the analytics tables.

Comment: I ended up having to create a custom test runner. It allows me to mark a database as "legacy" in my Django settings, and during test setup, the runner will simply skip over any databases flagged that way. I can share the implementation somewhere if it would be useful to you.

Comment: Yes, that would be of help. Maybe you can edit your answer?

Comment: MIRROR options doesn't work if underlying databases are different (MySQL, postgres)

Comment: This answer should be marked as the best one!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get a solution to ignore the first database creation, but you can reuse an existing database if all migrations have been created on it.

Usually, I execute my *Django* tests with **pytest** using the below setup:
[image]

Pay attention to the last field: *Additional Arguments*.

Its value is: `--exitfirst --reuse-db`. Using **pytest** with this additional arg also works on the command line, but I prefer PyCham because of Debugger.